# Why does this use of JavaScript's find() method return undefined?

Tags: javascript, find

I ran into this (unexpected) bug while trying to make a JavaScript function that gets a single post by id, from an array of objects:

```js
let posts = [
    {id: 1, title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"},
    {id: 2, title: "Numquam natus culpa non dignissimos dicta"},
    {id: 3, title: "Tenetur culpa accusamus"}
];

let singlePost;

function findById(array, id) {
  singlePost = array.find(function(post){
    console.log(post.id);
    return post.id === id;
    });
}

singlePost = findById(posts, 2);
console.log(singlePost);
```

For a reason I have not figured out, `console.log(singlePost)` outputs `undefined`.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: your function does not return anything, so `singlePost = findById()` sets the variable to `undefined`.

Comment: Ah, of course, silly me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your function is returning `undefined` and you are assigning it to `singlePost`. You can check below.

```js
findById(posts, 2);
console.log(singlePost); // This will console.log the value of singlePost
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a variable without the function returning anything, so replace the assignment of the variable within the function with a return

```js
let posts = [
    {id: 1, title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"},
    {id: 2, title: "Numquam natus culpa non dignissimos dicta"},
    {id: 3, title: "Tenetur culpa accusamus"}
];

let singlePost;

function findById(array, id) {
  return array.find(function(post){
    return post.id === id;
    });
}

singlePost = findById(posts, 2);
console.log(singlePost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the function was not returning the `singlePost` itself. Here is what I should have done:

```js
let posts = [
        {id: 1, title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"},
        {id: 2, title: "Numquam natus culpa non dignissimos dicta"},
        {id: 3, title: "Tenetur culpa accusamus"}
];

let singlePost;

function findById(array, id) {
  singlePost = array.find(function(post) {
    return post.id === id;
  });
  return singlePost;
}

singlePost = findById(posts, 2);
console.log(singlePost);
```